# Debug.WriteLine(string, params object[]) is a method but is used like a type

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging

I'm currently working on a **To-Do list** project and I am at the ending stages of development, however my syntax for outputting to the debug seems to be incorrect, I'm not sure what the error is and any help would be appreciated.

As shown above, the error is [CS0118](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzc6hyft%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> 'System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string, params object[]) is a method but is used like a type'

```
#define testing
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

#if(testing)
    public static string[] tempStringArr = new string[5] 
        { "Hey", "Greetings", "Hello", "Hi", "Example" };
    public static string tempKey = "Hello";

    public static int linearSearchTitleTest(string titleKey, string[] titleArr)
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < titleArr.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (titleKey == titleArr[i])
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    int testResult = linearSearchTitleTest(tempKey, tempStringArr);
    Debug.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(testResult));
#endif
```

Comment: Look again, you are writing code outside of a class! move your code inside a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Debug.WriteLine` call is not in the scope of a function. Try to put this code in a function, maybe in `main()` for testing purpose?

```
int testResult = linearSearchTitleTest(tempKey, tempStringArr);
Debug.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(testResult));
```

For example :

```
class Program
{
    public static string[] tempStringArr = new string[5] { "Hey", "Greetings", "Hello", "Hi", "Example" };
    public static string tempKey = "Hello";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int testResult = linearSearchTitleTest(tempKey, tempStringArr);
        Debug.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(testResult));
    }

    public static int linearSearchTitleTest(string titleKey, string[] titleArr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < titleArr.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (titleKey == titleArr[i])
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, cheers. I thought you could perform a #if #endif statement outside of a method, I didn't realise it had to be enclosed in one.

Comment: @PTR01 indeed you can use #if outside methods, you can even comment completely invalid code like your sample with `#if`, but it should not be evaluating to `false` (like `#if false`) to avoid compilation of such code.

Answer (score 1):

C# is an objective language. Meaning: all code must be part of an object.

Try wrapping your code in a namespace, a class, and a method. Usually this something like

```
namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // your code here ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note:  "is an objective language. Meaning: all code must be part of an object." - there is no direct correlation between "object oriented" and "code must be part of an object"... Otherwise ok answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually by using conditional compilation you are telling the compiler you want to compile which parts of your code and which parts you want not to compile and apparently these parts wont be in any form in the final compiled file. You can use reflector and other IL preview tools to check it .

Nevertheless after including and excluding these parts your code should be in correct format in the compiler view otherwise the compiler can't do its job.

In the other words `#if`  , `#else` and `#endif` can not and will not change the compiler behavior whatsoever but they change the code before any compilation takes place.